# Conflict between jQuery and f:ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jsf

My jQuery function is never called when I click on my submit button.

Nevetheless, jQuery detects the click if I remove the **f:ajax** line at **h:commandButton**.

How can I make it work **f:ajax** and my **jQuery** function together ?

**XHTML:**

```
<h:form>
    <!-- my inputs-->
    <h:commandButton id="submit-button" type="button" value="Confirm" >
        <f:param name="id" value="#{param.id}" /> 
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@none" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('input[id*="submit-button"]').click(function() {
  console.log("button clicked");
}); });
```

Comment: Look into the rendered response. The id of the submit button should be prepended with respective parent component's ids such as `form:submit-buttom` (unless `prependId` associated with `<h:form>` is set to false which in turn, is not recommended).

Comment: I've already tried with `form:submit-buttom` syntax. As I said, jQuery detects the click only if I remove the `<f:ajax>` line. It looks like the problem coming from ajax...

Comment: Why don't you use `onclick` attribute of the `<h:commandButton>` to call js function?

Answer (score 0):

*i would write this as a comment, but its too long, so i write it here as an answer.*

i guess you have a JS-Error prior this:

```
// prior this code you could have a JS Error    
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('input[id*="submit-button"]').click(function() {
      console.log("button clicked");
    });
});
```

so every JS Code after that JS-ERROR won'T work.

possible cause could be a missConfiguration of xhtml. i assume that your JSF-Ajax calls don't work too, this happens if you don't include `<h:head></h:head>` in your xhtml.

`<h:head></h:head>` tag must be included in order for ajax to work properly.

what happens in your case is: you are trying to make an ajax-request, this fails because JSF couldn't load jsf.js to your xhtml header, this cause a JavaScript Error, and every thing after this error won't work properly.